# Why is the slideup called twice (intermittent issue)?

Tags: jquery, double, slideup

I have a function which I call the slideup with additional tasks/steps.  Intermittently, the slideup code within the function is called twice.  Can someone spot what I did wrong?

Global Variable

```
    var currIndex = 0;
```

The function with the issue

```
    function PreNext(direction) {
        alert('Test #1');
        var thisMaxlen = homes.length - 1;  // homes is an array.
        var ctrl_toolTip = $('#controlSlideShow .tooltip');

        $(ctrl_toolTip).slideUp('slow' function () {
            alert('Test #2');

            if (direction == 'Next') {
                (currIndex >= thisMaxlen ? currIndex = 0 : currIndex++);
            }
            else {
                (currIndex <= 0 ? currIndex = thisMaxlen : currIndex--);
            }
        });
        alert('Test #3');  
    };
```

Intermittently, the slideup is called twice.
The result

```
    Test #1
    Test #2
    Test #2
    Test #3
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that come to my mind is that you are getting more then one elements in `ctrl_toolTip`

Just make sure that `$('#controlSlideShow .tooltip');` returns only single element.

Comment: Thanks for responding Talha.  I too had also thought that maybe the reason.  However I am sure there is only one .tooltip element.  To be certain, I used $(ctrl_toolTip).length and it returned 1.

Comment: Hmmm, Thats strange, Can you make a fiddle (jsfiddle.net) of that to make it more clear. Then i guess i would be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  I wasn't able to figure why the double pass was occurring.  However I was able to put in a workaround to accommodate the double pass.

```
    function PreNext(direction) {
        alert('Test #1');
        var dblPassFix = 0;                 // To fix the double pass in the slideup
        var thisMaxlen = homes.length - 1;  // homes is an array.
        var ctrl_toolTip = $('#controlSlideShow .tooltip');

        $(ctrl_toolTip).slideUp('slow' function () {
            alert('Test #2');
            dblPassFix++;

            if (direction == 'Next') {
                (currIndex >= thisMaxlen ? currIndex = 0 : currIndex++);

                if (dblPassFix > 1) {
                    currIndex--;
                }
                ...
            }
            else {
                (currIndex <= 0 ? currIndex = thisMaxlen : currIndex--);

                if (dblPassFix > 1) {
                    currIndex++;
                }
                ...
            }
        });
        alert('Test #3');
      };
```